# jquery ui spinner strings

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

Can anyone suggest analog of spinner from jQuery UI, that has ability to display strings instead of specific values? In my example I have two widgets, spinner and select, where select shows string "Foobar" when values is -1, but I want to use spinner to not to bound values to ones from list. http://jsfiddle.net/andrewboltachev/qk6bn/

I want actual plugin to have options like these:

```
$('#myspinner').spinner({
    'min': -1,
    'values_to_text': function(x) {
        if (x === -1) return 'FooBar';
        return x;
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe there are two separate issues here. One, you want to extend a Jquery function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/ The second issue is how you will configure this function so that it accepts those values.

Comment: But my question is mostly about jQuery UI spinner functionality, which I want to be extended. I want spinner to be a bit like standard HTML select widget

Comment: Can you use the event change of the spinner to set the value of the select? Change function: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change So instead of returning a value, just set it using JQ $(select).val('FooBar')